# Jquery Attribute Selector not working on first change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where I calculate total amount without tax of an item (`Item Price * Quantity - Discount%`).

On this total amount without tax, I have option to add either VAT or SAT or both. As I check the VAT amount, the Total Amount should be displayed in a textbox (`Total Amount Without Tax + VAT/SAT`). This functionality is implemented in `calculateTotalBill()` function. The problem is it displays `NaN` on very first change event of `Checkboxes` (`VAT/SAT`). On subsequent change events the function works fine.

Below is the snippet

```js
    function getPrice(element) {
        var itemPrice = $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1) input');
        $itemId = $(element).val();
        itemPrice.val(5);
        calculateAmount(element);
    }

    function calculateAmount(element) {
        var itemPrice = $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1) input').val() == "" ? 0 : $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1) input').val();
        var quantity = $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2) input').val() == "" ? 0 : $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2) input').val();
        var discount = $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3) input').val() == "" ? 0 : $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3) input').val();
        var amount = $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(4) input');
        var calcAmount = parseFloat(itemPrice) * parseInt(quantity) - (parseFloat(itemPrice) * parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(discount) / 100);
        amount.val(calcAmount);
        calculateTotal();
    }

    function calculateTotal() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#mptblBill tbody tr').each(function () {
            sum = parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat($(this).find('td:eq(4) input').val());
        });
        $('#txtTotalWdoutTax').val(sum);
    }

    function calculateTax(element) {
        var amount = $('#txtTotalWdoutTax').val();
        var taxAmount = amount * parseFloat($(element).val()) / 100;
        if ($(element).is(":checked")) {
            $(element).closest('td').next('td').find('input').val(taxAmount);
        }
        else {
            $(element).closest('td').next('td').find('input').val(0);
        }
        calculateTotalBill();
    }

    function calculateTotalBill() {
        var amount = $('#txtTotalWdoutTax').val();
        var taxTotal = 0;
        $('#calcTable tbody tr').each(function () {
            var a = $(this).find('td:eq(1) input[name^="txt_"]').length;
            var b = $(this).find('td:eq(1) input[name^="txt_"]').val();
            if (a > 0) {
                taxTotal = parseFloat(taxTotal) + parseFloat(b);
            }
        });
        $('#txtTotal').val(parseFloat(amount) + parseFloat(taxTotal)); 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 95%;" id="mptblBill" class="no-footer dataTable" role="grid">
    
    <tbody>
            
    <tr role="row" class="">
                <td>
                    <select onchange="getPrice(this);" id="ddlItemId_0">
                            <option value="1">Crocin Medicine</option>
                            <option value="3">DCold Total</option>
                            <option value="4">Rice</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="width100" value="" id="txtItemPrice_0"></td>
                <td><input type="text" onchange="calculateAmount(this);" class="width100" value="" id="txtQuantity_0"></td>
                <td><input type="text" onchange="calculateAmount(this);" class="width100" value="" id="txtDiscount_0"></td>
                <td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="width100" value="" id="txtAmount_0"></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="width100" value="+" id="btnAdd_0"></td>
            </tr></tbody>
<thead>
        <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 216px;">Item Name</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 188px;">Item Price</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 188px;">Quantity</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 188px;">Discount</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 188px;">Amount</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 109px;">Action</th></tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<table id="calcTable" style="width:100%; margin-left:32%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <label class="pullRight">Total Amount Without Tax </label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" style="width:188px;" value="" disabled="disabled" id="txtTotalWdoutTax">
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"> 
                    <input type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTax(this);" value="12" style="display:inline" id="chkTax_1" class="pullRight"><label style="display:inline" class="pullRight"> VAT - 12 % </label> 
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" style="width:188px;" value="" disabled="disabled" name="txt_1">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"> 
                    <input type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTax(this);" value="2" style="display:inline" id="chkTax_2" class="pullRight"><label style="display:inline" class="pullRight"> SAT - 2 % </label> 
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" style="width:188px;" value="" disabled="disabled" name="txt_2">
                </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <label class="pullRight">Total Amount </label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" style="width:188px;" value="" disabled="disabled" id="txtTotal">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: exits both values ? parseFloat(amount) + parseFloat(taxTotal)

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón I do not understand. `amount` is the Total Amount without Tax. `taxTotal` is the Tax on the amount.

Comment: one of both values or is String or is not defined

Comment: Both are getting calculated and displayed in their respective textboxes also

Comment: use parseFloat(Number(amount)) + parseFloat(Number(taxTota)l), but one of both is bad at the begin try to see out in console

Comment: Tried this its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
function getPrice(element) {
        var itemPrice = $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1) input');
        $itemId = $(element).val();
        itemPrice.val(5);
        calculateAmount(element);
    }

    function calculateAmount(element) {
        var itemPrice = $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1) input').val() == "" ? 0 : $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1) input').val();
        var quantity = $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2) input').val() == "" ? 0 : $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2) input').val();
        var discount = $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3) input').val() == "" ? 0 : $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3) input').val();
        var amount = $(element).closest('tr').find('td:eq(4) input');
        var calcAmount = parseFloat(itemPrice) * parseInt(quantity) - (parseFloat(itemPrice) * parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(discount) / 100);
        amount.val(calcAmount);
        calculateTotal();
    }

    function calculateTotal() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#mptblBill tbody tr').each(function () {
            sum = parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat($(this).find('td:eq(4) input').val());
        });
        $('#txtTotalWdoutTax').val(sum);
    }

    function calculateTax(element) {
        var amount = $('#txtTotalWdoutTax').val();
        var taxAmount = amount * parseFloat($(element).val()) / 100;
        if ($(element).is(":checked")) {
            $(element).closest('td').next('td').find('input').val(taxAmount);
        }
        else {
            $(element).closest('td').next('td').find('input').val(0);
        }
        calculateTotalBill();
    }

    function calculateTotalBill() {
        var amount = $('#txtTotalWdoutTax').val()==''?0:$('#txtTotalWdoutTax').val();
        var taxTotal = 0;
        $('#calcTable tbody tr').each(function () {
            var a = $(this).find('td:eq(1) input[name^="txt_"]').length;
            var b = $(this).find('td:eq(1) input[name^="txt_"]').val();
            if (a > 0) {
                taxTotal = parseFloat(taxTotal) + parseFloat(b==''?0:b);
            }
        });
        $('#txtTotal').val(parseFloat(amount) + parseFloat(taxTotal)); 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 95%;" id="mptblBill" class="no-footer dataTable" role="grid">
    
    <tbody>
            
    <tr role="row" class="">
                <td>
                    <select onchange="getPrice(this);" id="ddlItemId_0">
                            <option value="1">Crocin Medicine</option>
                            <option value="3">DCold Total</option>
                            <option value="4">Rice</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="width100" value="" id="txtItemPrice_0"></td>
                <td><input type="text" onchange="calculateAmount(this);" class="width100" value="" id="txtQuantity_0"></td>
                <td><input type="text" onchange="calculateAmount(this);" class="width100" value="" id="txtDiscount_0"></td>
                <td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="width100" value="" id="txtAmount_0"></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="width100" value="+" id="btnAdd_0"></td>
            </tr></tbody>
<thead>
        <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 216px;">Item Name</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 188px;">Item Price</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 188px;">Quantity</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 188px;">Discount</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 188px;">Amount</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 109px;">Action</th></tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<table id="calcTable" style="width:100%; margin-left:32%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <label class="pullRight">Total Amount Without Tax </label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" style="width:188px;" value="" disabled="disabled" id="txtTotalWdoutTax">
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"> 
                    <input type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTax(this);" value="12" style="display:inline" id="chkTax_1" class="pullRight"><label style="display:inline" class="pullRight"> VAT - 12 % </label> 
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" style="width:188px;" value="" disabled="disabled" name="txt_1">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"> 
                    <input type="checkbox" onchange="calculateTax(this);" value="2" style="display:inline" id="chkTax_2" class="pullRight"><label style="display:inline" class="pullRight"> SAT - 2 % </label> 
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" style="width:188px;" value="" disabled="disabled" name="txt_2">
                </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <label class="pullRight">Total Amount </label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" style="width:188px;" value="" disabled="disabled" id="txtTotal">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```